# Internal Server Error 500 while calling the API

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, fetch-api

I am fetching an API signup/validateOtp for validating the OTP. In body I am passing the mobile number and OTP but I am getting the Internal Server Error.

Following is the code for fetching the API-

```
onSubmitOtp = () => {
    console.log(this.state.mobile);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.otp));
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://35.154.16.105:8080/signup/validateOtp',{
        method:'post',
        headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            mobile: this.state.mobile,
            otp:this.state.otp
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
        if(data.content === 'OK'){
            // this.props.loadNewUser(this.state.otp);
            console.log(this.state.mobile);
            this.props.onRouteChange('createprofile','nonav');
        }
        else
         console.log(data.error);
    })
    this.props.onRouteChange('otp','nonav');
}
```

[image: API]

Error-
Otp.js:19 POST https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://35.154.16:105:8080/signup/validateOtp 500 (Internal Server Error)

[image: Log]

Comment: @JaromandaX I have changed the API' last 3 digit before posting

Comment: Ok, so now check the backend logs at 35.154.16.000 to see what is causing the server to send error 500

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry I have corrected it now.

Comment: Well, check the server logs for the cause of the error 500

Comment: Actually I am just handling the front-end part. I have added the log screenshot.

Comment: Well, it's a backend error - so, contact them

Comment: From your hardly readable screenshot, it looks like you are sending an invalid HTTP request. Try not using that `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` site.